# Making python like system calls in java

Tags: java, python, shell, unix, runtime.exec

Is there an equivalent to Python's popen2 in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `Process` object is what you're looking for. Javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). You use it something like `Process myProcess = System.getRuntime().exec("cmd here"));` It allows you to get the standard and error output streams.

Answer (score 3):

[`System.getRuntime().exec(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

`System.getRuntime()` yields the Runtime object, from which you can make various `.exec(...)` calls that spawn a `Process` object. This has input and output streams and a status.